Is there / Should there be a reference list of banned AI tools?
My understanding is that AI tools must not be used to help generate answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/gen-ai-policy
It is not necessarily clear from a product's website if it counts as such a tool.
For example, I just flagged a Perl answer generated by using https://codeconvert.ai to convert Python. In this case, the product website states:

The conversions are performed by a customized AI language model to the best of its understanding and does a great job on a good range of conversion tasks. However, different programming languages implement programming constructs differently. Also, some tasks may not even be directly possible in some programming languages. Thus, we cannot say that the conversions will always be exactly correct.

So this site falls under the ban. But another site may not make such a clear statement, leaving one to have to guess if generative AI is being used.
If there is not already a help page (or meta question) explicitly listing banned tools, would it make sense for there to be one?

I mean... if you have to ask whether or not text being generated by a tool is gen AI or not, it probably is.

Honestly if an answer is determined to be "generated" by any tool, it should be banned regardless of what the tool says it is.

@kmdreko yacc? lex? gperf? cpp?

If we're being realistic, if it is an AI tool, it'll likely be painfully obvious. Companies love slapping an AI label on their products

@jhnc I meant specifically the whole of the answer generated based on the original question.

@KevinB the example I gave is a code translator, it doesn't write text. But consider historical a2p and s2p that attempted to convert awk/sed into Perl. Not AI, also not perfect.

There is an implicit list in the policy you linked: by saying "all", the list covers any and all possible generative AI tools that have ever been or will ever be created.

@TylerH I was more interested in the gray area of tools that aren't obviously AI but as noted by Zoe above it's probably not big

Would you consider "All of them" to be a useful list? I could probably add that to the FAQ if you really want...

@CodyGray not necessary but thanks for the offer. I think the scores on the question and answer show the general feeling

A good heuristic is probably something like "can the tool generate an answer if a question is pasted into it?"

If all GenAI tools that generate code are banned, then the list, would be impossible to create since it would be infinite

There's no gray area. If and when a gray area pops up, we'll deal with it then.

If it says "a customized AI language model" that's referring to a generative AI, and likely a LLM (Large Language Model) at that.

@Laurel that's why I wrote second last paragraph above: "So this site falls under the ban. But another site may not make such a clear statement, leaving one to have to guess if generative AI is being used."

The list is simple: *

The post I closed this as a duplicate of is clear IMO: all use of generative AI is banned.

The list can be created off-site, it is pretty common to create lists of things in github. Like this: https://github.com/sedyh/awesome-ebitengine . Lists of Things and Stack Overflow don't really mix, it is more something that people will start to feel very protective of (or in other words, "own") rather than it actually being useful to someone.  And in this case it's going to be a list of products so I imagine it'll also attract quite some advertising attention / spam.

No, there shouldn't.
A ban-list would only serve for users to be able to say “this specific tool wasn't banned when I posted”.
Playing whack-a-mole with these tools as they appear, isn't practical or useful.
A simple “all gen AI tools are banned, unless explicitly allowed” rule, is more than enough.

"Playing whack-a-mole isn’t practical or useful." - especially given how many AI companies keep popping up for a little while before dying. There's so many tools and it's so easy to spin up a new wrapper around the OpenAI API that trying to maintain a list is futile and, as you already note, will only serve to cause lots of rule lawyering and unnecessary discussions when the goal is "all genAI tools are banned"

sounds like SO needs a clause like University of Cambridge's :  "Finally, users are also expected to be guided by common sense. Over-pedantic interpretation of the Rules or these guidelines is no substitute for common sense; a failure to act sensibly may in itself be regarded as a breach of the Rules."

btw, I don't see any "unless explicitly allowed" type wording on the policy page. So presumably any such allow list is currently empty?

@jhnc yes, currently there's no allowed gen ai tool.
